# showing induced homomorphism is trivial

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the sphere $$S^2=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.$$
Identify the unit circle $S^1$ with
$$\{(x,y,z) \in S^2 \mid\ z=0\}.$$
Let $F:S^2 \rightarrow S^1$ be a map and consider its restriction to the equator $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ defined by
$$f(x,y)=F(x,y,0).$$
I would like to show that the induced homomorphism
$$f_*:\pi_1(S^1,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1,y_0)$$
is trivial.

 I know that somehow I have to use the fact that the upper hemisphere of $S^2$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk and then consider the restriction of $F$ to the upper hemisphere $\{(x,y,z) \in S^2 \mid\ z \geq 0\}$, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Let $\iota:S^1→ S^2$ be the identification $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$. Then $f=F\circ\iota$ so by functorality, $f_*=F_*\circ\iota_*$. But $\iota_*:\pi_1(S^1,x_0)\to\pi_1(S^2,\iota(x_0))\cong 0$ must be the trivial map, so $f_*$ is as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $f=F\circ i$, where $i:S^1\hookrightarrow  S^2$ is the inclusion.

But, $S^2$ is simply connected $\implies F_*$ is trivial.

So $f_*=F_*\circ i_*$ is too.